# Delphi 64-bit Preview Compiler available?

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction, 64-bit, delphi-2010

is there a 64-bit preview compiler available, as announced a long time ago? I wasn't able to find anything.

I really need a 64-bit compiler to target the 64-bit versions of Microsoft Office.

Comment: I would really like to see a 64-bit preview compiler too. It's just not good enough that they're so far behind the field in this area.

Comment: This historical question is no longer useful.  The 64 bit compiler was released later than some people might have hoped, and is stable now.  Delphi XE2 and XE3 both ship with 64 bit delphi compilers.  As of 2013, this question is of only historical interest now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not yet.

According to the [latest roadmap](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39934) Delphi X and Chromium seem to be the current priorities, followed by Commodore, so I'm not sure when a 64 bit preview compiler will be available.

If you want an early peek at these things, it might be worth [signing up for the betas](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/beta-programs).

Comment: According to the *previous* roadmap we should already have a release quality 64-bit compiler and IDE buid environment.  The current "roadmap" (a seemingly random assemblage of PowerPoint slides) probably does more to undermine confidence in the direction of the product than it does help, not least because the "RoadMap" for the "future" [hard to tell since it isn't dated] contains things that have *already* *happened* or been more formally announced).  As a result I use only as an example of how *not* to do a RoadMap (for an example of "good", I use: http://www.remobjects.com/ROadmap.aspx).

Comment: Correction:  The *slides* in the [Delphi] so-called "roadmap" are dated, but the roadmap itself is not.  The date on the slides is somewhat suspect and simply adds to confusion however since the slides talk about a release that had already happened (Weaver == Delphi 2010) in a way that is *impossible* to distinguish from the way in which future "blue sky releases" ("Project X" etc) are "discussed".

Comment: It is astounding that they a) haven't released a 64-bit compiler yet and that b) it doesn't seem to be a top priority for them.

Comment: I've asked Michael Rozlog from the Delphi compiler team. He responded: "I can't give any hard dates, right now we are working on cross-compilation and then it will be 64 bit.  It will be a while before we are done with the cross-compiler, but as soon as it is, we are planning on starting the 64 bit right-away." Sounds good, but for the 64-bit compiler it means: they haven't even started yet. :-(

Comment: @Stefan - Trust me, they've started, so at least some of the work is being done in parallel.  You also shouldn't consider the cross platform work to be completely separate from the 64 bit work.  They will both be taking advantage of cross compilation.  http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39174

Comment: Both cross platform and x64 work require many common underpinnings. Think about how debugging is going to work for instance.  The debugger must be effectively a "remote debug" even on Win64 local machine debugging.  Thought of that deltics? I didn't think so.

Comment: If there was a requirement to use remote debugging from the same platform for both client and server, we could live with it. We can't however live without 64bit compiling. I hate to write parts of my applications in Visual Studio but that's what I'm forced to do now.

Answer (score 5):

You could try FPC: http://www.freepascal.org/

Comment: While COM has improved significantly in the last months, it is probably not up to snuff enough for Office integration.

Comment: Thank you, this will definitely be worth a try. With Office integration I mean low-level Extended MAPI integration, maybe the COM improvements are enough to do this.

Comment: FPC has absolutely rotten support for BPL-style packages (okay, basically none), which might be a deal-breaker for some people.

Comment: Other than that, it's pretty amazing if you want Delphi code to compile on Mac or 64-bit Windows. :-)

Comment: It is much easier to use CodeTyphon, which is an easy one click installation package for cross platform native Delphi like RAD/IDE based on Lazarus/FreePascal. CodeTyphon already supports 4 CPU/OS hosts (Win32, Win64, Linux32, Linux64), and 16 CPU/OS targets (arm-Wince, arm-Linux, arm-Embedded, arm-gba, arm-nds, i386-Win32, i386-Linux, i386-FreeBSD, i386-Haiku, x86_64-Win64, x86_64-Linux, x86_64-FreeBSD, powerpc-Linux, powerpc64-Linux, sparc-Linux, sparc-Solaris). http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=96&catid=68&Itemid=147

Answer (score 3):

Yes, see http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/64-bit
and [What should be tested in 64-bit Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549276/what-should-be-tested-in-64-bit-delphi)

Answer (score 3):

Trial version of Delphi XE2 are now available: https://downloads.embarcadero.com/free/delphi .

Answer (score 2):

I just received an e-mail about the 64-bit Beta.  http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/64-bit
Looks like priority goes to registered XE users, and you'll need to sign an NDA and you cannot distribute apps built with the beta.

Comment: Just received another e-mail on this an hour ago, pushing the RAD Studio XE promotion.