# Delphi compiler for 64bit computers

Tags: delphi, 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delphi 64-bit Preview Compiler available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789741/delphi-64-bit-preview-compiler-available)

Hello!

I know this message will annoy some people, but anyway...

Does anybody know if something is going on with 64bit Delphi?
Does Embarcadero or anybody else developing compiler for 64 bit computers?
Can we expect something in near future?

I looked arround and found very different information, but it would be good to know
to be prepared when everybody will start using 64 bit computers.

Any information will be much appreciated.

Petra.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to give up dependence on the VCL, FPC and Lazarus can build 64-bit code.

Comment: Actually I have a long Delphi program so I would like

Comment: Lazarus has a VCL substitute, LCL.

Comment: @Marco: Sure, but the hard part is third-party components.

Comment: IMHO the debugger is a bigger problem than that. So much is ported, if you know where to look.

Comment: You can write a 64 bit non GUI application using FPC, then interact with it from a 32 bit Delphi applications, with all third-party components you need for your User Interface. Interaction can be through named pipes or windows GDI messages (even lighter).

Answer (score 3):

Officially, information about future editions of Delphi and C++ Builder is presented in "Roadmaps". The latest Roadmap can be found here:

- http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39934

This is a slide from the presentation:

[image]
<sub>(source: [embarcadero.com](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/images/39934/0300000C.png))</sub>

Comment: Reading that sounds like they are going x64... of course, that was posted over a year ago.

Comment: @Chris: August 12, 2010? Was that over a year ago? Then I am really late with a few projects...

Comment: They have an amazing language with a great infrastructure that only needs a few components and a server adapter to run web apps, but instead they're adding support for... PHP. @#$^!@#$%@#^!

Comment: @Andreas: The COMMENTS on that article start in September 2009.  My guess is they just changed the date.  They were planning on releasing a "preview" of the 64 bit compiler in 2009..  That didn't happen.

Comment: @Chris: Please name a few IDE, FrameWork and compiler vendors that deliver new and stable things on time...

Comment: @Ignacio - is the end part of your comment PHP? It looks a bit like it, sorry $it.

Comment: @Jeroen: There is a difference between On Time and being several years late to the party...  Most compiler vendors had complete and stable x64 versions years ago.

Answer (score 3):

The official statement for 64-Bit is here: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39174

In short: 64-Bit requires many changes to the compiler and they are working on it.

Answer (score 1):

"64 bit computers" run current 32bit Delphi executables just fine.

Some people need 64bit executables to access more memory and/or to write drivers, but in my opinion most people don't need 64bit Delphi.

Comment: 1982 - "Wow, the 80286 can handle up to 16MB of RAM! Too bad no one will ever need that much to write a program" ;-)

Comment: That is what I need, to access memory over 2GRam. Thank you all.

Comment: There are several questions on SO about how to access up to 4GB from 32bit Delphi programs. -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740308/why-2-gb-memory-limit-when-running-in-64-bit-windows

Comment: Of course people want, and sometimes need, x64 to do specialized stuff, for instance because x64/x86 thunking in Windows can't be done like in the old 16/32-bit days. Even big companies like Microsoft cannot get it right (there are some x86 things in Office that are not available in the x64 version).

Comment: that setting {$SetPeFlags IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE} will enable us to use over 2GRam on 64 bit computers. But if I put it to my dpr, when compiling it produces an error: Undeclared identifier. I am using Delphi XE. Is this not available anymore or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I found out: I should add 'windows' in uses in my dpr file.

Comment: You can use a memory-mapped file bigger than 2 GB in plain 32 bit mode. You just have to map your file by blocks smaller than 2 GB. If you have enough RAM on your computer, there will be no file written on disk.

Comment: You should read Fedro, "nondum matura est..."

Comment: -1.  Answering "It's not needed" is not an answer for someone enquiring about the compiler's progress.  Plus, of course, just because you don't think it's needed doesn't mean you're right - in my opinion (and naturally I think I'm right :p) 64-bit compiler support will be very useful for a wider audience than just writers of drivers.  For example, Explorer plugins, performance optimisations due to available registers, thunking, >4GB memory (which is not that much any more, you know!), etc.  Note that you can't really compile drivers with Delphi at the moment anyway.

Comment: @David M, the question makes multiple references to "64 bit computers" and none to compiler, so I think my answer is relevant (and the 4 upvotes would seem to agree)

Comment: Jasonpenny, the question (which doesn't show as edited to me) includes the phrase "compiler for 64 bit computers".  Regardless, I stand by my response to an answer basically saying "it's not needed", which is often not a useful kind of answer to give, especially in an area like this where that's very arguable.

Answer (score 1):

As Andreas pointed out, the most recent word is that they're planning on having a 64-bit compiler in the next preview.  With so much to be done, I wouldn't be surprised if the beta cycle for it started real soon, maybe even before the new year.

Keep checking the forums and the Embarcadero blogs ([DelphiFeeds.com](http://delphifeeds.com) is a good place to keep abreast of all the news) and you'll probably hear about it starting soon enough.  Sign up for the beta and you'll get a chance to test out the 64-bit Delphi system and provide feedback that may even shape the development of the product.